# How to use task module in teams to show interactive charts?

Tags: node.js, chart.js, botframework, microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

I am building a teams bot using a Botframework SDK 4.0 , which shows interactive charts when a user requests it in the chat. Currently i can only generate a chart using Chart.js and convert it to an image and send it to the teams bot as an attachment.
I want to make these charts interactive so i want to open a task module when the user clicks a button on an action card.
But even after the reading the documentation, i don't understand how to implement the task module itself and also how i would render the javascript and html.

If anyone can break it down or point me in the right direction, it would be incredible helpful.

Comment: Task modules in Microsoft Teams allow you to create modal pop-up experiences in your Teams application. They can be used to run your own custom HTML or JavaScript code, show an <iframe>-based widget, or display an Adaptive Card.
To implement a task module, you would need to use the Microsoft Teams JavaScript client library (TeamsJS). If you have built a tab, you're already familiar with creating a task module as they are essentially a tab inside a pop-up window.
Here's a basic example of how you can invoke a task module from a bot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HtXn.png

Comment: In the above code, we're creating a Hero Card with a button that, when clicked, will invoke a task module. The value object is sent to your bot when the button is clicked. The type property is set to task/fetch to tell Teams to fetch the task module.
When the button is clicked, your bot will receive an invoke activity with the name task/fetch. Your bot should respond to this activity with a TaskModuleResponse object: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9GrH.png.

Comment: In the above code, we're responding to the task/fetch invoke activity with a TaskModuleResponse object. The url property of the taskModuleInfo object is the URL of the page that will be displayed in the task module.
To render JavaScript and HTML in the task module, you would need to host a web page that includes your JavaScript and HTML code. This page will be displayed in the task module when it is invoked.
For more information, you can refer to the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/task-modules/task-modules-bots?tabs=nodejs documentation.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT Thanks for the elaborate explanation, i have finally managed to invoke the task module, but i am trying to display the youtube webpage as a start in the task module and it is giving me the error "unable to reach app. please try again".
it is also accompanied with this error:https://ibb.co/Jz1PQ1L

I have added youtube in the valid domains in the manifest file like this: "validDomains": [ " * ", " * .youtube.com" ],

Comment: You can refer these samples once, they show youtube video inside task module - https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-task-module, https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/app-task-module

Answer (score -1):

Create a Task Module:

In Microsoft Teams, use the Task Module to design an interactive chart experience.
Integrate Chart Content:

Embed your chart content within the Task Module using web pages or adaptive cards.
Enable User Interaction:

Leverage the Task Module's capabilities to allow users to interact with and manipulate the chart data dynamically.
Deploy in Teams Tabs or Messages:

Once configured, deploy your Task Module with interactive charts either within Teams tabs or directly in chat messages for a seamless user experience.